# How to find only one class in a html that is exactly the same and have two classes with the same name when clicked with a mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have two exactly the same html code my html code is this one:

```
<body>
<div class="1">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>

<div class="1">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
</body>
```

as u can see the html code is exactly the same. What i need to do is when i click on the div with a class of 1 to make the background of ONLY the closest div with a class of 3 and NOT all classes with 3. For example when i click on the first div of class 1 to only make the first div with class 3 with a red background.

i tried a few things using jquery, but none of them worked for me. here is my current jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".1").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().closest(".3").css("background", "red");
    });
});
```

thank you!

Comment: `closest()` searches UP the DOM hierarchy, not in siblings.

Comment: Also calling `parent()` will go up to the body and lose the context of the div you originally clicked, so the idea of the closest div doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example using the structure you have. Remove the `.parent()` and replace with `.nextall('.3:first')`. nextAll will hunt through the siblings of the clicked div finding the first one one that matches our selector `.3:first`. `.3` being the class and `:first` being a pseudo selector for the first matched result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".1").click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll(".3:first").css("background", "red");
    });
});
```

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyd9tkvx/)

Comment: it dosent work the way i want to work. i dont want to select all the .3 classes i only want to select the closest one to the class of .1 that someone clicked to. for example if you click on the first .1 class then it should select ONLY the first .3 class (make the background red) and if you click on the second .1 class to only select the second .3 class (div)

Answer (score 2):

As all your `div` are siblings of each other, you need to find the next `div` unitl the one with a class of `.3`. For this use the `nextUntil()`. This will get you the second `div`. Now do a `.next()` to get to the target `div`.

***Note***: It is a good practice to *not* start your `id` or `class` names with a number. Although, HTML5 allows it, CSS/CSS3 still has problems dealing with them cleanly.

***Snippet:***

```js
$("div.1").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("div.3").next().css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 20px; height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div class="1">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".1").click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil(".3").next().css("background", "red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way the list can update data by ajax 
[My code is here](http://codepen.io/nailu0/pen/OPVoYK)

```
$("body").on("click","div.1",changeBackground)

function changeBackground(){
    $(this).nextUntil("div.3").css('background','lightgreen');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's "your" html code, why don't you put another container around both sections...

```
<body>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="1">1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div class="3">3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
    </div>    
    <div class="section">
        <div class="1">1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div class="3">3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

...and then do something like:

```
$(this).parents('.section').find('.3').css()
```